# how to make button submit value only on click in node js and ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have this in ejs file with a button, I want it to only submit value to app.js when only clicked but right now it instantly sends the value when program runs.

```
<% notesArray.forEach((note,i) =>{ %>
<div class="note">
  <h3> <%= note.title %> </h3>
  <p> <%= note.text  %> </p>
  <form class="" action="/" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="deletebutton" class="deleteButton" value=<%-note.title-%>><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

Here I have this variable "submitFromButton" which instantly gets a value when program runs but I only want value from it when use clicks the button in ejs file I mentioned above

```
 app.post("/",function(req,res){
       var note = {
         title:req.body.inputTitle,
         text:req.body.inputText,
         inputValue:req.body.submitButton
       }
       if (note.inputValue == 'note'){
         notesArray.push(note);
       }
        var submitFromButton = req.body.deletebutton;  // here is the problem
         console.log(submitFrombutton);
```

Comment: Make sure that you are not using  `$().submit()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean "when program runs" ? Your code is in an app.post() function, so it can only be triggered when a form is posted, not when the page is displayed.

Seems like something else is posting a form, or you have a piece of code posting automatically.